# Django collectstatic not working using django-storages (with AWS)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a django site and can not get the `manage.py collectstatic` command to complete. It collects the majority of files but never finishes... returns the below traceback. I am using django1.3 and python2.7.

Also, `DEBUG = False` and `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` is in my installed apps.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 80, in handle_noargs
    for path, storage in finder.list(ignore_patterns):
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 210, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(self.storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 21, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
    File "/home/rowapparel/.virtualenvs/dev_ra_env/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 109, in listdir
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Again, it works for a lot of my static files, but not all. It seems to stop at the same file everytime, but when I ignore that app and/or file it still returns the above traceback.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the django-storages [docs](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html), the proper way to have collectstatic put files in your s3 bucket is to define the following in your settings:

`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'`

... **you can not** use `storeages.backends.s3.s3Storage` as that backend does not define the listdir method... the boto backend does.